# JasperReports localization: using expression in $R{}

Tags: localization, jasper-reports

I need to localise field values in my *JasperReports* report. For example in my sql query I have a Gender field. If it have a value of *1* I would like it to display Male and for *0* Female.

I have the following in a text field in my report

```
$R{"gender" + $F{GENDER}}
```

Then in my report.properties file I have

```
gender1=Male
gender0=Female
```

But this does not work I get a error when its parsing the statement.

Does any body know how to do this.

Comment: The variable looks like the perfect solution however the variable need to be evaluated for each row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *str()* function instead of using `$R{}` expression.

Try this expression:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[str("gender" + $F{Gender})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

#### The sample

The csv datasource (*names.csv*) file:

```
Name,Gender
Mikle,1
Lisa,0
John,1
Linda,0
```

The properties file (*genders.properties*):

```
gender1=Male
gender0=Female
```

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="genders" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" resourceBundle="genders" uuid="1ceeef64-2e53-404a-ae1b-9896b8b749cf">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Gender" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="6b27452c-b5f1-4aa3-a4f2-9ae239ff244c" x="0" y="0" width="106" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="b0fcb296-b20b-4171-803d-639754edbc31" x="106" y="0" width="162" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Gender}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="587d47c0-3908-464b-852a-3009e98def01" x="268" y="0" width="287" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[str("gender" + $F{Gender})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image]